# Remote Error Message in MVC2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

HI,
I have created an applicaiton in MVC 2.0 . I deployed the application on win server 2008.
I used [HandleError] attribute in controller class.
i have error.aspx in our project for error redirect.
in web.config Customerrors mode is On.
but when i acces the website from client machine i got the following error

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

can anyone help for this.

Thanks.

Ashok.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to configure the error handling of IIS 7.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
     <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" defaultPath="~/Your error page">  
          <clear/>  
      </httpErrors>  
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```